# Parsing song names and the like from a XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Haven't asked a question on SO in a while for fear of being blasted, but I'm really stuck.

Yes, I have looked at the other answers to parsing from a XML file. By some combination of my incompetence and my inexperience, I can't seem to parse information from an XML file describing a playlist I made.

I have no experience parsing XML files but I still don't see what I'm doing wrong. As a novice in this area, I'd like answers that teach rather than just recommending such and such library, as that's no way to learn.

---

Here's the top of the XML file and the first song in the XML file I'm parsing. Sorry I don't have a generalized version of this, as I suspect my problem may arise from the design of this file, but I'd be glad to be wrong.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Date</key><date>2015-10-05T09:48:26Z</date>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>12.2.2.25</string>
    <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
    <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>4EFDC340CA35F4A8</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>1467</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>1467</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Gorgeous (feat. Kid Cudi &#38; Raekwon)</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Kanye West</string>
            <key>Album Artist</key><string>Kanye West</string>
            <key>Composer</key><string>Che Smith/Mike Dean/Corey Woods/Ernest Wilson/Roger McGuinn/Scott Mescudi/Gene Clark/Malik Jones</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>My Beautiful Dark Twisted Fantasy</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>Hip Hop</string>
            <key>Year</key><integer>2010</integer>
        </dict>
```

(I tried to cut out as much extraneous file info as possible.

My immediate goal is to be able to print out some simply formatted information in the vein of:

```
Song Name: "Gorgeous" | Artist: "Kanye West | Album: "MBDTF"
```

etc.

I've tried lots of stuff, mostly [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Here's one of the codes I tried:

```
docroot = ElementTree.parse('MyPlaylist.xml').getroot()

for child in docroot:
    for dict in child:
        for a in dict:
            print a.tag, a.attrib
```

That just prints out the baffling

```
key {}
dict {}
key {}
dict {}
key {}
#and so on...
```

I tried further nesting but it returns the same or similar.

---

Reminder: I HAVE looked at the other answers to "how to parse XML with Python," but I really just don't get it. I believe I've exhausted the resources at hand right now and need someone to give me a few pointers. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Song Name i.e. `Gorgeous` is substring and from where you get Album value i.e. `MBDTF`

Comment: @VivekSable I get that but I don't know how to access it. Can you write an answer for me?

Comment: we want Name, Artist, Album ?

Comment: Yeah. Ignore my sample output as I realize it doesn't match the XML file. I don't need help formatting the output, just accessing the correct elements would be enough :)

Comment: can I use `lxml` or `xml.etree.ElementTree` ?

Comment: @VivekSable I'll take whatever you got if you can explain what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is simple code to get song details from the dict tags. Add comment in the code.

**input**:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Date</key><date>2015-10-05T09:48:26Z</date>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>12.2.2.25</string>
    <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
    <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>4EFDC340CA35F4A8</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>1467</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>1467</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Gorgeous (feat. Kid Cudi &#38; Raekwon)</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Kanye West</string>
            <key>Album Artist</key><string>Kanye West</string>
            <key>Composer</key><string>Che Smith/Mike Dean/Corey Woods/Ernest Wilson/Roger McGuinn/Scott Mescudi/Gene Clark/Malik Jones</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>My Beautiful Dark Twisted Fantasy</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>Hip Hop</string>
            <key>Year</key><integer>2010</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>

    <dict>
        <key>1468</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>1468</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>test name</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>test Artist</string>
            <key>Album Artist</key><string>test Album Artist</string>
            <key>Composer</key><string>test Composer</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>test Album</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>test Genre</string>
            <key>Year</key><integer>2010</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Demo**:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#- Parser content by fromstring method of ElementTree
root = ET.fromstring(data)
#- Get all targeted dict tags from the content plist->dict->dict 
target_dicts = root.findall("./dict/dict")
#- Variable whoch store taget information.
resut_info = []
# Iterate target dict tag.
for i in target_dicts:
    #- Find dict tag from the dict tag.
    target_dict = i.find("dict")
    #- Get children of target dict tag.
    dict_children = target_dict.getchildren()
    #- Tmp variable which save all details.
    dict_details = {}
    #- Iterate over children.
    for j in dict_children:
        #- As structure well define so we can use following logic to get key and value.
        if j.tag=="key":
            tag_key = j.text
        else:
            dict_details[tag_key] = j.text

    resut_info.append({"Name":dict_details.get("Name", ""),\
                       "Artist":dict_details.get("Artist", ""),\
                       "Album":dict_details.get("Album", "")})

import pprint
pprint.pprint(resut_info)
```

output:

```
[{'Album': 'My Beautiful Dark Twisted Fantasy',
  'Artist': 'Kanye West',
  'Name': 'Gorgeous (feat. Kid Cudi & Raekwon)'},
 {'Album': 'test Album', 'Artist': 'test Artist', 'Name': 'test name'}]
```

Comment: can you remove `?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">` from the input file and try again ?